# ngAnimate doesn't animate on ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm having a really hard time understanding ngAnimate.

HTML:

```
<body ng-init="hide=false">
<button ng-click="hide=!hide">Toggle</button>
<div class="item" ng-hide="hide">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-hide-add, .ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}

.item {
  padding: 40px;
  background: orange;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  transition: all linear 3s;
}

.item:hover {
  background: red;  
}

.item.ng-hide-add {
  background: red;
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rixKjjvy4TUiu1r3MSFm?p=preview

The hover transition works fine, but the ng-hide-add doesn't animate at all.

Comment: I'd recommend moving transition properties into `ng-hide-add` and `ng-hide-remove` and styling the active classes for `item` if this is the effect you're after: http://plnkr.co/edit/0GgeNtdm0J4ZmXqsmfOg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, using .item.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active instead of .item.ng-hide-add was all it took. I don't understand why this change was necessary though. .item.ng-hide-add does match the item as well, right?

Comment: To understand why Angular requires you to style the `-active` class in order to animate, refer to [`$animate.addClass()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate#addClass).